# Consuming from multiple topics using single kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

which one is recommended to use : 
1. Single kafka stream consuming from multiple topics
2. Different kafka streams consuming from different topics (I've used this one already with no issues encountered)

Is it possible to achieve #1 ? and if yes, what're the implications?
and if I use 'EXACTLY_ONCE' settings, what kind of complexities it'll bring?

kafka version : 2.2.0-cp2

Comment: Depends on your requirements and architecture.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to achieve #1 (Single kafka stream consuming from multiple topics)

Yes, you can use [StreamsBuilder#stream(Collection<String> topics)](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#stream-java.util.Collection-)

If the data that you want to process is spread across multiple topics and that these multiple topics *constitute* **one single source**, then you can use this, but not if you want to process those topics *in parallel*.

It is like one consumer subscribing to all these topics which also means one thread for consuming all the topics. When you call `poll()` it returns `ConsumerRecords` from all the subscribed topics and not just one topic.

In Kafka streams, there is a term called Topology, which is basically a *acyclic graph* of sources, processors and sinks. A topology can contain sub-topologies.

Sub-topologies can then be executed as independent stream tasks through parallel threads ([Reference](https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-kafka-streams-applications/))

Since each topology can have a source, which can be a topic, and if you want parallel processing of these topics, then you have to break-up your graph to sub-topologies.

> If I use 'EXACTLY_ONCE' settings, what kind of complexities it'll bring?

When messages reach *sink* processor in a topology, then its *source* must be committed, where a source can be a single topic or collection of topics.

Multiple topics or one topic, we need to send offsets to the transaction from the producer, which is basically `Map<TopicPartition, OffsetMetadata>` that should be committed when the messages are produced.

So, I think it should not introduce any *complexities* whether it is single topic having *10* partitions or 10 topics with 1 partition each, because *offset* is at the *TopicPartition* level and not at topic level.

Comment: When I started with a kafka-stream consuming from TOPIC1 and doing some parsing with `EXACTLY_ONCE` settings. Everything is working fine. But the issue started occurring (timeout) is when I added another kafka topic(TOPIC2) to the same stream. The error is given below :

Comment: `ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask - task [1_0] Timeout exception caught when initializing transactions for task 1_0. This might happen if the broker is slow to respond, if the network connection to the broker was interrupted, or if similar circumstances arise. You can increase producer parameter `max.block.ms` to increase this timeout.`  AND `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.`

Comment: @kuti Did you try the workarounds mentioned, like increasing the `max.block.ms` or checking the conncectivity of your broker?